# Redirection of stderr does not work when applications is excecuted as part of a cronjob

Tags: cron, stderr

when calling

```
/home/username/temp/build/appname 2> /home/username/temp/log/stderr 1> /home/username/temp/log/stdout
```

both stderr is redirected to /home/username/temp/log/stderr, and stdout is redirected to /home/username/temp/log/stdout.

However, when adding a cronjob

```
5 * * * * username /home/username/temp/build/appname 2> /home/username/temp/log/stderr 1> /home/username/temp/log/stdout
```

The application runs as expected, stdout is redirected to /home/username/temp/log/stdout, **but stderr is empty**.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
The top of /etc/crontab is

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
```

**The issue seems to be exclusive to my (commandline qt) application.**
The following cronjob works with correct redirection of stderr:

```
* * * * * username ls /doesnotexist 2> /home/username/temp/log/ls_stderr
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your distribution it might be that crontab is using a different shell than your are expecting. Two solutions come to mind:

1. Set the shell in crontab

   Add `SHELL=/bin/bash` (or whichever shell you prefer) to the top of your crontab
2. Use the redirect syntax of the shell crontab is using

   You can find the shell by adding

   ```
   * * * * * echo $SHELL > $HOME/cronshell
   ```

   to your crontab. It will most likely be /bin/sh, which again depending on your distribution might be symlinked to a different shell. [Here](http://hyperpolyglot.org/unix-shells#redirection) you can find a great summary of different shell redirection syntaxes.